# Right place for styles file in Angular

Tags: angular

I have seen a lot of templates that they put their style files (*.css  | *.scss)  in a folder named theme under the app module.

Why they do not put their style files in the **assets** folder ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about *theme* but *assets* folder is a bit conterintuitive place for styles. It is usually used for storing media files and fonts. Component specific styles are usually placed in same directory with *template* and *.ts* files. Shared styles can be placed on *app/styles* level like so:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you see the angular.json file, you see that, in the "tag" "styles" you see this .css

Tipical you see

```
"build": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
    "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/demo",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
              "themes/customTheme.css" //<---THIS line
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
```

This make that Angular use all the .css in styles -and the css you writ in each component- to join in an unique .css. So you can put the general .css in the folder you choose always you include in the angular.json file. Well, really you **NOT put in the assets folder**. The assest folder are for all the rest of static files you has (images, .json...) because this folder is copy to the dist folder, and if you include the file in angular.json Angular is yet included

Answer (score 1):

Typically, the assets folder would be used for static files such as images or for files to be used as is.  [Angular Documentation on application source files](https://angular.io/guide/file-structure#application-source-files) There is nothing really stating that you need to use a specific folder structure for storing css files.  So developers using the theme folder may be using it as a personal preference because the css files within it may provide common look or feel to their app.  They may be using a library such as Angular material which use themes to provide global styling to the components in the library.  These themes help define the colors and general style of the components provided in the material library.  Angular material allows you create custom themes to use instead of the default themes provided and typically I have seen developers store their custom material css files in a theme folder.